# pytest running tests multiple times

Tags: python, pytest

I have a `pytest.ini` file that has the following contents

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests/database/* tests/*
addopts = -v --cov="merlot"  --cov="merlot/sql" --cov-report term-missing
```

My tests are structured such that

```
tests | test1.py
      | test2.py
      |
      | subfolder | test3.py
                  | test4.py
                  | test5.py
```

When I have `testpaths = tests/*` then no tests in `subfolder` are run, however the current invocation runs the tests in `subfolder` multiple times. The result looks like

```
tests/database/testDatabase.py::TestMerlotDB::testDbName PASSED                                                                                              [ 12%]
tests/database/testDatabase.py::TestMerlotDB::testResetIndex PASSED                                                                                          [ 25%]
tests/database/testDatabase.py::TestMerlotDB::testInsertRecord PASSED                                                                                        [ 37%]
tests/database/testDatabase.py::TestMerlotDB::testDbName PASSED                                                                                              [ 37%]
tests/database/testDatabase.py::TestMerlotDB::testResetIndex PASSED                                                                                          [ 37%]
tests/database/testDatabase.py::TestMerlotDB::testInsertRecord PASSED                                                                                        [ 37%]
tests/testMerlot.py::TestMerlotBrowser::testBrowser PASSED                                                                                                   [ 50%]
tests/testMerlot.py::TestMerlotBrowser::test_go_to_URL PASSED                                                                                                [ 62%]
```

How can I fix my `pytest.ini` file so that the unit tests only run one time?

Comment: Why `tests/database/* tests/*`? You're asking pytest to recurse the same directories twice, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your `pytest.ini` so that the unit tests only run once:

```ini
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
python_files = test*.py
```